# Unexpected behaviour seq() function

Tags: r

I tried `seq(0:2)` and it has a weird output. Basically,
Why:

```
seq(from= c(0,1,2))
```

outputs:

```
1 2 3
```

?

Comment: What do you expect that to return?

Comment: It seems as though if a vector is included it returns the length of the vector as the max number for the sequence. In your case since you have 3 values in the vector, it returned `1, 2, 3`

Comment: From the docs (my emphasis): *"seq is generic, and only the default method is described here. Note that it dispatches on the class of the first argument irrespective of argument names. This can have unintended consequences **if it is called with just one argument intending this to be taken as along.with**: it is much better to use seq_along in that case."*.

Comment: Please read the docs before posting: "`seq(from)` [...] generates the sequence `1, 2, ..., length(from)` (as if argument `along.with` had been specified), _unless_ the argument is numeric of length 1 when it is interpreted as `1:from`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you pass a vector of length > 1 to `seq`, its semantics mirror that of `seq_along`, or of `seq(along.with = …)`. That is, it gives you a vector of indices of that vector:

```
seq_along(0 : 2)
# [1] 1 2 3
seq(along.with = 0 : 2)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Bizarrely, `seq` is *not* implemented in terms of `seq_along`, and the latter is probably more efficient. Instead, the current (R 4.1) implementation of the relevant part of `seq` looks as follows.

```
lf <- length(from)
return(if (mode(from) == "numeric" && lf == 1L) {
    if (!is.finite(from)) stop("'from' must be a finite number")
    1L:from
} else if (lf) 1L:lf else integer())
```

And the implementation of `seq(along.with = …)` is still different:

```
length.out <- length(along.with)
return(if (length.out) seq_len(length.out) else integer())
```

… which, incidentally, is redundant; it could be shortened to the following:

```
length.out <- length(along.with)
return(seq_len(length.out))
```

… honestly, the implementation of the default `seq` function is a bit of a mess.